# PHP Get Javascript Variable Without Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, joomla

Click div > popup > display everything from database (via php).

How can I get the javascript variable to be used in PHP for the WHERE clause in my sql statement?

Eg:

```
$(".divclass").click(function(){
     <php
          $sql = "select * from table where id = ".[the div id];
     ?>
});
```

is there anyway to get it besides using ajax and post via form method? also without the dom

Thanks!

Comment: [**read more**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming) about diff b/w server side and client side programming

Comment: This just wont work. You need to think about what you're actually trying to do a bit more. What are you trying to do by the way? When clicking your div what are you trying to get to happen?

Comment: You can't take back database data without asking by server side code, which implies to use PhP or another server-side language. Plus, if you want your code not to reload the whole page, you are forced to use AJAX methods to take your data, and display them without altering the rest of your DOM.
Did you tryied to take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ ?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible in PHP.

PHP is a server side language, you can't pass him variables without a call to php script.
Javascript is a client-side language and it is NOT secure.

The best answer for your question is :

- Use JS on client-side to get the ID
- Call from JS (ajax for example) a PHP script and send it the ID in parameter (post/get).
- On server-side (php), you make the SQL request (and secure the ID : intval()) and you get the result.
- From php you send back the result (json for example).
- JS get the result and parse/use it !